# XPage is completely blank

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage that includes some static html at the top, some edit fields to enter search criteria, a data table to display the search results and a button to refresh the id of the data table to display the search results.

When I launch the page initially it displays fine, includes default data in the data table and all is good.  When I click the button, the page loses all content - including the static html at the top.

There is no error message on the server console, there is nothing in the firebug console that would indicate any errors. Firebug shows the html on the page consists of the following:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Any thoughts on where my content is going ?  I would expect at least the static html to display or an error message on the console, but nothing...

Comment: Strange one.  Try comparing with local history to see what has been recently changed.  Go in to the source pane, and then right click, choose "Compare With" | 'Local History...".  You can compare the newest code with older versions and it highlights what has changed.

Comment: Or maybe copy all the source XML to somewhere, delete the page and re-create it. Sounds like there went something wrong with the Java source in the back.

Comment: Post sample XSP source.

Comment: I did the source compare and it highlighted a few verbiage changes, and the inclusion of some csjs code.  I backed those changes out and same results.

Comment: Also tried copying source, deleting xpage, create xpage and copy source back.  Same results.

Comment: Is there anything in the xpage beforeRenderResponse event?  As has been said, posting sample XSP will help get answers.

Comment: Can you post your xml definition here so we can find any issues on the xml? It's quit hard to find out what's wrong if we dont have the code that is causing the error.

Comment: In Firebug, on the Net tab, it shows a post but no response.  I don't know enough about the post content to know what it should look like, but methinks the post content is interrupted.  And what's the best way to post source code ?  Stackoverflow newbie here...

Comment: Its a bit tricky to paste code, you have to put 4 spaces before each line.   It can take a while to get it right.  Let me ask, are any other xpages or older domino web apps able to run on the same server?  Have you had a chat with your Notes admin?

Comment: Many other xpage apps and web apps running on the servers.  I've created many myself.  We also have several other very similar types of apps that have some search text and a refresh button to redisplay data.  Stole(borrowed) the code off the net a while ago and has been working great.  So, the post from firebug can be found here:  http://www.wolfjawtcs.com/xpagecode/xpagepost.pdf  and the source code of the xpage can be found here:  http://www.wolfjawtcs.com/xpagecode/reportPortal.xsp

Answer (score 0):

I looked at you code.   You do have a BeforeRenderResults event that calls javascript that I don't have access to.   First thing remove this event, and you should at least see something in your browser.   It seems to be acting as an "Xagent".  Something in your code is doing something and never finishing, so your page is never rendered.

If I remove that event myself, I get other errors after that because I don't have your SSJS library called  "/SortableSearchResults.jss".   Also , check that file extension, shouldn't it be just ".js".

Comment: The extension for client JS libraries is .js. The extension for server JS libraries is .jss.

Comment: You can name your SSJS library whatever you want, f.e. *MyLib.honkytonky*.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on the file extension.  It didn't look funny until I saw it typed in my SO answer.

Comment: I've stripped most all code from the xpage and have some static html and a button that does a full update remaining.  Page launches as expected with the static html and button.  Clicking the button results in a completely blank page.  I'm probably missing something obvious here but what ???

Comment: I can't recreate your xpage due to not having the SSJS lib.  Is the button supposed to reload the current xpage with new values? If yes, look carefully at this method SearchResults.buildPageContent() which is in the beforeRenderResults.  Like I was saying earlier, if it messes up you could get a blank page.  You could use the SSJS debugger if you are using R9, or just put a bunch of print() statements in that code.  Your browser gives no errors because it is serverside.  Check your server logs for unreported errors; look here ->"data/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT".

Comment: You prob know this, but the print() statement show in the server console, and logs.  Don't forget to post the result here when you figure it out.